# Hibernate throwing java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value exception for @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

Tags: java, hibernate

This issue is happening for one of my entities, while I managed to make it work for another after making sure I was dropping the tables involved, so that Hibernate was auto generating the column correctly.

Both the entities have this annotation -

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Enum.TxnSource source;
```

My Enum looks like -

```
public enum TxnSource {
        API,
        DASHBOARD_BULK_UPLOAD
        ..
    }
```

And service looks like -

```
TransactionRequest transactionRequest = transactionRequestRepository.
                        findBy..(..);
                
                transactionRequest.setStatus(status);

transactionRequestRepository.save(transactionRequest);
```

Similar operations are being done for the other entity as well, but I am getting the following exception -

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at 

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:545) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
..
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.service.Service.method(Service.java:364) [classes/:?]
        at com.service.Service$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$90d728db.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
 
..

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'SMART_SEND' for column 'source' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:?]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:177) ~[hibernate-envers-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:47) ~[hibernate-envers-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:945) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:520) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 115 more
```

Comment: Because you're using `EnumType.STRING`, the name of the enum value will be used (string) instead of its ordinal (number). Your database column then needs to be of a string type, e.g. VARCHAR with MySQL. I bet it currently is of a number type, e.g. INT.

Comment: The db column is varchar. I dropped the table and let hibernate re create it. Still this issue.

Comment: @SandeepanNath What hibernate version, hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @SternK Hibernate-core:5.2.14.Final and org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect.

Comment: The issue got resolved after I dropped the db and let hibernate recreate it. Not sure what was wrong and can I be sure if this won't happen in production, if we manually make the alter table changes. I think auto creation is not enabled there.

Comment: I got the same issue today, and the issue was coming from Audit tables(using hibernate envers). 
I was dropping only the entity table. And now i can see hibernate-envers in your stacktrace